# Example of a metric with negative scalar curvature everywhere on a sphere $S^n$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature, spheres

According to corollary 8.5.3 in [1], "There are no topological obstructions to negative Ricci or scalar curvature in dimensions at least $3$." More specifically, theorem 4.1 on page 8 in [2] says "Any smooth compact manifold $M^n$, $n\geq 3$ has a metric with negative scalar curvature."

This is surprising to me — so surprising that I find it hard to imagine. To cure my lack of imagination, I'll ask for an example...

For some $n\geq 3$, what is an example of a Riemannian metric defined everywhere on the sphere $S^n$ with everywhere-negative scalar curvature? I'm hoping for something written in the form
$$
 ds^2 = \sum_{jk} g_{jk}(x) dx^j\,dx^k
$$
with the coefficients $g_{jk}(x)$ given by explicit functions of the coordinates $x$, in some set of coordinate-patches that collectively cover the sphere.

---

**References:**

[1] Tuschmann and Wraith (2010), *Moduli Spaces of Riemannian Metrics*, https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-0348-0948-1

[2] Notes by Li on Schoen (2017), "Topics in Scalar Curvature," https://geometrysummer.math.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/2312/2018/06/Schoen_spring_2017__Topics_in_scalar_curvature.pdf

Comment: The result is also mentioned in Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_curvature, weirdly under positive scalar curvature. According to the linked page on prescribed scalar curvature, by work of Kazdan and Warner, "If the dimension of M is three or greater, then any smooth function ƒ which takes on a negative value somewhere is the scalar curvature of some Riemannian metric" (M is assumed to be a smooth closed manifold).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used a CAS for the scalar curvature but I am sure it is not too hard to compute it by hand.

On $S^3$ take the Berger metric (also known as a squashed sphere),
\begin{equation}
g=\eta _1^2+b^2\eta_2^2+c^2\eta_3^2
\end{equation}
with $\eta_i$ left-invariant forms on $SU(2)\simeq S^3$.

A possible parametrisation is
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\eta _1 &= \sin \psi \, \mathrm{d} \theta - \cos \psi \sin \theta \, \mathrm{d} \phi ,\\
\eta _2 &=\cos \psi \, \mathrm{d}  \theta + \sin \psi \sin \theta \, \mathrm{d} \phi,\\
\eta _3 &= \mathrm{d} \psi + \cos \theta \,\mathrm{d} \phi,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$b,c$ are constants. The round metric on $S^3$ has $b=c=1$. We have $\theta\in[0,\pi]$, $\phi\in[0,2\pi)$, $\psi\in[0,4\pi)$.

The scalar curvature of this metric is
\begin{equation}
s= - \frac{1}{2 b^4c^4} [b^8+(c^4-1)^2-2b^4(c^4+1)]
\end{equation}
which clearly can be made negative by an opportune choice of $b,c$. For example for $b=1$,   $s=2-c^4/2$ is negative for $c^4>4$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer (+1)! This seems to be exactly what I wanted. For etiquette, I'll wait a while before accepting it, and in the meantime I'll spend some time checking it so I can reap some intuition. By the way, the expression you wrote for $s$ can also be written
$$
 s = \frac{4B-(1+B-C)^2}{2BC}
$$
with $B=b^4$ and $C=c^4$.

Comment: Just curious: what does CAS stand for? Computer-Aided-...?

Comment: Glad it was useful. It stands for Computer Algebra System!